# Condition format color cells until sum equal to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel file and I need to color the cells in a row until the sum of them reach the number of the selected cell. But if the sum on the cell is only partially covered that cell needs to be colored only partially.

Here is an example that maybe you will understand better:

> 31.000 **0 0   4.000   8.000   4.000   4.000   4.000   0   4.000   4.0**00

Here I want that the last cell to be also colored but only half because the sum from the BOLD contains also an amount from the last 4000 but not totally. What I want looks something like this:

[image]

Another example with extra cells:

> 2.240  **0 0   640 960 640**   640 640 960 640 960

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with two conditional formatting rules. First, select all the cells you want to have this formatting style.

Then, on the Home ribbon, select `Conditional Formatting > New Rule`. Choose `Use a formula to determine which cells to format` and enter the following in the box under "Format values where this formula is true:"

```
=SUM($B2:B2)<=$A2
```

Replace both instances of `B2` with the address of the top left cell of the range you are applying the formatting to. Replace `A2` with the address of the target value for the first row of data.

Click `Format...` to set the format to a solid cell fill (green in my example). Click OK.

Then, repeat this process to create another rule with the formula:

```
=AND(SUM($B2:B2)>$A2,SUM($B2:B2)-$A2<B2)
```

Set the formatting for this rule to a vertical gradient going from the color for the other rule to white. You can do this by choosing `Fill Effects` when setting the cell formatting.

Example:

[image]